# T-SQL computed date column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table, in TSQL, with a field containing data in YYYYMMDD format saved as varchar(50);

I want to add a date type column to the table for each of the corresponding records in this field.
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question well... Do you want to replace the `varchar` column with the `date` one?

Comment: You can do it using - `ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD YourColumnAsDate AS CONVERT(DATE, YourColumn, 112);` - But the real question has to be, why would you store dates as a VARCHAR? and why when that varchar has a fixed format which is 10 characters long would you use `VARCHAR(50)`? A more robust long term solution would be to alter your table to make sure [data is stored in the appropriate type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type).

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx explains what @GarethD suggests.

Comment: Be warned, that you will get errors unless your computed column is persisted, it does not validate your dates, so you could have something like - `CREATE TABLE #T (A VARCHAR(10), B AS CONVERT(DATE, A, 112)); INSERT #T (A) VALUES ('20150532');` - as you can see 32nd May is inserted which is not a valid date, then if you run something as simple as `SELECT * FROM #T` you will get an error. If you have a column that uses the correct type, then you get this error on the insert, and stop the invalid data at source.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have stored correct format of date in your field (eg you don't have '20121433'), this script should works for you:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
ADD your_field_Date DATETIME

UPDATE your_table 
SET  your_field_Date = CONVERT(DATETIME, your_field_varchar, 112)

ALTER TABLE your_table DROP COLUMN your_field_varchar
```

Comment: 105 is not correct. It should be 112 since the original format is YYYYMMDD.

Comment: The reason I ended with data as a varchar was due to a migration from a flat file which was not properly formatted. I'll give your response a try and revert. Again, thanks.